# Swift PDFDocument return nil for files and urls

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, fatal-error, ios-pdfkit

I want to show a PDF file using PDFView in an iOS app. I have added a file called merlin.pdf to my project directory. I have also checked that merlin.pdf is included in the Copy Bundle Resources in Build Phases. But still, PDFDocument returns nil. This is the code I'm using:

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class ReaderViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "merlin", withExtension: "pdf")
        let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url!)

        pdfView.document = pdfDocument
        pdfView.displayMode = PDFDisplayMode.singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.autoScales = true


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

The fatal error is thrown at `pdfView.document = pdfDocument`.

Then, I tried an online link to the PDF file. While debugging, I can see that `let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url!)` is donwloading the file from the internet. But again, it fails just like last time. This is the code:

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class ReaderViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.10760.pdf")
        let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url!)

        pdfView.document = pdfDocument
        pdfView.displayMode = PDFDisplayMode.singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.autoScales = true


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well strangely enough, the problem was with the `weak` keyword in `@IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!`. Removing the `weak` made the code work.
Thanks to @klinki for mentioning the outlet.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you missed to set the class of the view in the interface builder for your pdfView outlet?[image]

Because your code is fine and works for me.